# Log4j not printing complete stack trace

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

**I checked all the answers in the SO**. But none really helped me.

**My Log4j property file**

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,console,file

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=eseries.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n %throwable{short}
```

**My log4j version**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.11</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Loggin Format**

```
    logger.error("*****Error Id is:"+errorId+"\t" , e);
```

**What I am getting**

I am just getting the `e.getMessage()` in the log. Not the complete log trace.

Any suggestion?

Comment: %throwable{short} is the problem, it is suppressing the stack trace

Comment: you can also have a look at the [api](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html) for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of your conversion pattern

```
 log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n %throwable{short}
```

Here is excerpt from `ThrowableInformationPatternConverter`

> Outputs the ThrowableInformation portion of the LoggingEvent. By
>   default, outputs the full stack trace.
>
> **%throwable{none} or %throwable{0}** suppresses the stack trace.
>
> **%throwable{short} or %throwable{1}** outputs just the first line.
>
> **%throwable{n}** will output n lines for a positive integer or drop the last -n lines for a negative integer.

You need to remove `%throwable{short}` to see full stack trace

Comment: Seem like the default only print 135 lines then it stops with something like ...98 more